# How to add fields to the main table instead of cstm table

Tags: php, sugarcrm, custom-fields

I am using Sugarcrm 6.5 and I want to ask if it is possible for me to create fields inside the main table instead of the cstm table. Right now I am create custom fields via this post
http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.1/70_API/Application/Module_Loader/90_Package_Examples/Creating_an_Installable_Package_that_Creates_New_Fields/ and this method add custom fields to cstm table

When I look around, this below post (the last response said that it is possible)

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/how-take-out-_c-when-creating-custom-field-56452/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Maybe You Shouldn't

This is against standard best practices. The general reason is that if SugarCRM comes out with an update that happens to include a new field for this module, it'll overwrite what you already have and cause issues and/or data loss. It'll also be more difficult to tell that that this field is a custom one, which may make future customization from different developers/teams more difficult.

## But You Can

The acceptable "but" in this situation is that you can't keep the database's `fields_meta_data` table under version control. Not with GIT, not with SVN - you just can't. So, if you're working in a multi-developer or multi-system environment where you do pushes using VCS, it's actually preferable to hand-code your vardefs and it can be done in a relatively upgrade-safe way. Here's how:

Add the portion of your vardef that Studio won't allow you to adjust into your first vardef file, e.g.  `/custom/Extension/modules/MyModule/Ext/Vardefs/myfield.php`. For probably every field/data type, those vardefs are `name`, `vname` and `type`.

```
<?php
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['name']='myfield';
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['vname']='LBL_MYFIELD';
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['type']='varchar';
```

Once that's created you can run a repair-and-rebuild (which will also help set up your database, something like `alter table mymodule add myfield varchar(255)`) and then go find the field in Studio. Adjust the length or audit values if desired, and re-save the field. Studio will create a new file, prefixed with "sugarfield_," e.g. `/custom/Extension/modules/MyModule/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_myfield.php` The contents of this file will vary more by datatype than our first file, but will include something like the following:

```
<?php
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['audited'] = false,
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['massupdate'] = true,
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['duplicate_merge'] = 'enabled',
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['duplicate_merge_dom_value'] = '1',
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['merge_filter'] = 'disabled',
$dictionary['MyModule']['fields']['myfield']['calculated'] = false,
```

You should also create a language file at `/custom/Extension/modules/MyModule/Ext/Language/en_us.myfield.php`. Example contents for the language file:

```
<?php
$mod_strings['LBL_MYFIELD'] = 'My Awesome Field';
```

## Extra Safety

So if the down-side of hand-coding all of your custom fields is that they could be easily overridden but an update (e.g. you created a field called "Marketo ID" and then Sugar provides one), how can we reduce the risk of that? The same way we reduce the risk when creating custom modules - just prefix everything with some standard abbreviation for your system or company. At my current employer, we all use `tcx_` for Ticomix. In the past, we used `psi_` for Profiling Solutions. If instead of calling your field `myfield` you were to call it `tcx_myfield` you've greatly reduced the risk of someone else creating a field of the same name. It's not impossible, but you're probably pretty safe.

Note that you **do not** need to add this prefix to the labels. LBL_TCX_MYFIELD can translate directly to "My Field" and you can very easily adjust the label in the future if needed.

Comment: If it is possible please provide example like u said, the field type is 'varchar'. Thank you so much

Comment: Edited to give an example using type varchar.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew. It worked. I just want to ask 1 more question, where can I find reference to `name`, `vname`, `type` or `len`, because I want to set the default value as well. Also in the manifest file, I can set label `array('name' => 'calldate', 'label' => 'Call Date',`, however, if I ['label'] like your post, it does not work. It has to go through en_us.myfield.php

Comment: As far as I know, there is no single list of SugarCRM Vardef Paramters. The best reference is to dig through /modules/Accounts/vardefs.php and vardefs.php for other modules. I think you can use 'label' when defining the view in a metadata file, but it's not a vardef value. At least, it's not one I've ever used. You want to bring in a proper language file anyway in case you ever need to translate things for use with multiple languages. The param to set a default value is just 'default' and I'm updating my example with this.

Comment: For what it's worth, I totally flipped my position here. I'm now pro-hand-coded-vardefs.

Comment: @MatthewPoer why did you flip your position on vardefs? I'm a couple weeks into trying to customize SuagrCRM 8.0.1 and I don't think I've ever been this confused by a software package. That's saying a lot as I used to do JD Edwards ERP on IBM iSeries :).

Comment: @Dan I should probably update the answer (again) and give more context, etc, but my stance today is "it doesn't matter, because you kind of have to handle both." It's not that difficult to track key tables from the database (e.g. `fields_meta_data`) if you export per-table with per-record `INSERT`s. If you can export it then you can script it and track it. I have a (IMHO) pretty good system for doing this now. In 8+ years of Sugar work I've never seen a field naming collision, so I'm now a lot more confident with prefixed+hand-coded field names and comfortable tracking db tables when needed.